# MySQLi Query error Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the following error when I'm trying the code down below:

Error: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /volume1/web/index.php on line 4 Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /volume1/web/index.php on line 7 Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /volume1/web/index.php on line 23`

The code that I am using..

```html
<?php

// Connect to the DB
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost","root","","dbproject");

//Query the DB
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM clients");

// Count the returned rows
if($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id = $rows['id'];
        $fname = $rows['firstname'];
        $lname = $rows['lastname'];
        $country = $rows['country'];

        echo "<p>ID: " .$id. " <br /> Name: ".$fname." ".$lname. "<br /> Country: ".$country." </p>"; 
    }
// Turn the results into an array
// Display the results
} else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
}

?>
```

As the error reffers to line 4, 7 and 23

Line 4:

```
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost","root","","dbproject");
```

Line 7:

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM clients");
```

Line 23:

```
    echo $mysqli->error;
```

Can someone please help me with this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

I changed line 4 from:

```
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost","root","","dbproject");
```

to

```
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost:3307","root","","dbproject");
```

Adding the port somehow fixed it.

Comment: The port 3307 is defined in the configuration file of your db server (my.cnf, my.ini, or similar). The default one is 3306 for mysql.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried it on my server and I don't see anything wrong with it. Just make sure your login details are correct as wel as you database and table name.

This is the script I just tested on my server. I added a connection test and changed the database and table name:

```
<?php

// Connect to the DB
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
} 

//Query the DB
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM testing");

// Count the returned rows
if($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id = $rows['ID'];


        echo "<p>ID: " .$id. " </p>"; 
    }
// Turn the results into an array
// Display the results
} else{
    echo $mysqli->error;
}

?>
```